# Creating a Rock Papers Scissors Program and there seems to be an error in My Code

Tags: python, random, python-import

I'm just beginning to learn python. I'm creating a little rock paper scissors game.

Line 8 seems to be my problem ("def rock_logic():"). The VS studio code debugger says "invalid syntax (, line 8)pylint(syntax-error)"

I've looked through both Automate the boring things and Colts Steele's "The Modern Python 3 Bootcamp," but I can't seem to find the solution.

```
import random
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
user_choice = input()
comp_choice = random.choices()
print("ROCK! PAPER! SCISSORS!")

def rock_logic():
    if user_choice = 'rock' and comp_choice = 'rock':
        print ('TIE')
    elif user_choice = 'rock' and comp_choice = 'paper':
        print('YOU LOSE')
    else:
        print('WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER')

def paper_logic():
    if user_choice = 'paper' and comp_choice = 'paper':
        print ('TIE')
    elif user_choice = 'paper' and comp_choice = 'scissors':
        print('YOU LOSE')
    else:
        print('WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER')

def scissors_logic():
    if user_choice = 'scissors' and comp_choice = 'scissors':
        print ('TIE')
    elif user_choice = 'scissors' and comp_choice = 'rock':
        print('YOU LOSE')
    else:
        print('WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER')
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your code sample. Embedded tabs? Special characters? The line looks fine so there must be something sneaky going on there.

Comment: `=` is assignment operator, `==` is equality operator

Comment: I don’t think this is the cause of that syntax error, but not your logical comparisons should use `==` not `=`.

Comment: also you are missing the argument choices in the function ```random.choices``` it should be ```random.choices(choices)```

Answer (score 0):

The logical operator for equality is actually different than the assignment operator. When you want to do a comparison, you should be using `==` rather than `=`. For example, line 8 should read

```
if user_choice == 'rock' and comp_choice == 'rock':
```

As you can see, there are two equal signs rather than one for each one. This can lead to some nasty errors, and it appears to be leading to the one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the equality check using `==`, I think you are misusing the `random.choices()` method.  Consider the following proof of concept:

```
import random
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
comp_choice = random.choices(choices)[0]
print(comp_choice) 
# e.g. 'scissors'
```

`random.choices()` requires an argument -- the list of options that it will select from.  And importantly, it returns a *list*!  So we use the `[0]` to indicate that we want the first (i.e. zeroith) element from that list.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences

Lastly, it might be easier to compare the options in one go... e.g.

```
if comp_choice == user_choice:
    print('Tie')
elif comp_choice == 'scissors' and user_choice == 'paper':
    print('You lose)
```

The important thing is to keep at it -- eventually it will make sense.  Hope that helps!